# Error con rutas de archivo y caracteres de escape

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo usando la librería segyio y estoy pasando por los comandos básicos para familiarizarme, pero no he podido ejecutar el comando para leer un archivo seg-y. El error que me aparece es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\193.168.1.83\Daniel_Navarrete\PYTHON\SEG-Y READER\untitled0.py", line 14, in <module>
    with sgy.open(filename, mode ="r", endian='little', ignore_geometry=True) as f:
  File "C:\Users\GEOIL-08\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\segyio\open.py", line 162, in open
    fd = _segyio.segyiofd(str(filename), mode, endians[endian])
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Aqui mi script, es bastante directo para abrir el archivo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import segyio as sgy

#Main Program
filename= 'D:\PYTHON\SEG-Y READER\3D.sgy'
with sgy.open(filename, mode ="r", endian='little', ignore_geometry=True) as f:
    print(f.ilines)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema con las rutas es bastante común. Tu pregunta es un poco confusa porque en el texto pones una ruta, en el error otra y en tu script otra diferente.

Lo mejor y más conveniente es usar el módulo `pathlib` que te formatea la ruta de forma correcta sin importar qué sistema operativo uses.

Por ejemplo:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(r'D:\PYTHON\SEG-Y READER\3D.sgy')
```

...te devuelve

```
WindowsPath('D:/PYTHON/SEG-Y READER/3D.sgy')
```

Y podrás usar ese objeto como nombre de ruta. Échale un vistazo a la documentación de `pathlib` que es capaz de hacer cosas muy útiles.

Comment: Gracias, usando el pathlib ya no me genera error

Answer (score 1):

El caso es un problema de manejo de rutas de los lenguajes y Windows. Y ve familiarizándote con él, porque no es exclusivo de Python, casi todos los lenguajes se comportan igual.

Existen caracteres de escape: `'\p', '\n', '\t'... etc`. [Strings and Bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (ver la tabla) que coinciden con la forma en cómo implementa Windows en sus rutas de archivo, por ejemplo: `C:\Temp\test`

Adicional, hay algunos strings numéricos que Python los identifica como octal `\ooo` o hexadecimal `\xhh`.

```
>>> '\3' # interpretado como 3 en octal
'\x03' # 3 en hexadecimal
>>> '\16' # interpretado como 16 en octal
'x0e'
>>> '\12' # cuidado!
'\n'
```

Para escapar las secuencias de escape hay que utilizar doble barra invertida

```
>>> 'C:\Temp\test\script.py'
'C:\\Temp\test\\script.py'
 #       ^^ <-- esto es un tabulador.
>>> print('C:\Temp\test\script.py')
C:\Temp est\script.py # [!] Mal interpretado
>>>
>>> 'C:\\Temp\\test\\script.py'
'C:\\Temp\\test\\script.py' # Interpretación correcta
>>> path = '\\\\remote_server\\Shared'
>>> print(path)
'\\remote_server\shared' # Correcto
```

Puedes usar también **raw strings**

```
>>> r'C:\Temp\test\script.py'
'C:\\Temp\\test\\script.py' # Correcto
```

Para manejar rutas, recomiendo usar el módulo `os.path`. No uses `+` ya que hará menos portable entre plataformas tu código.

```
>>> import os
>>> path = r'C:\Temp\test'
>>> cfile = 'script.py'
>>> os.path.join(path, cfile)
'C:\\Temp\\test\\script.py'
```